# Do you get reputation from answers of yours that were migrated before you had an account on the destination site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migrated-questions

Sorry, I couldn't think of a shorter title for this question.

On Programmers.SE, I frequently see questions which have been migrated there from SO. Sometimes there are a few people who have answered those questions who do not have Programmers.SE accounts, so their name is grayed out. And sometimes those answers have quite a few upvotes, or are even accepted.

I am just curious, if one of those people later makes a Programmers.SE account, will they receive that reputation? Or is it lost forever?

Comment: May be you need to recalc your reputation at /reputation on destination site, once you created the account.

Comment: @YOU perhaps, I think that'd have a greater effect on reputation you had lost/gained on questions which had since been migrated though. Probably creating account is where a recalc (or I guess just a calc) would occur.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, no up and downvotes are harmed during the process.

When I made my Meta account I got around 400 reputation from migrated posts from stackoverflow.

I assume, your history is stored and when you create an account on the site, any post that could be linked to your account is added with your account. That's another reason to associate your accounts.